# Access to other control values when AjaxFileUpload fires UploadComplete event

Tags: ajax, file-upload, postback

My understanding is that the AjaxFileUpload object uses an iframe to upload files.  A postback occurs, but no other controls are posting back - at least that is what it looks like to me as I cannot access any other controls' data.

The purpose of the app is to allow the user to upload a file.  It will then modify the contents of that file and save the results to the server.  The problem is that it needs some extra information to make the modifications, and therefor needs the information that the user entered elsewhere on the page.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to do a postback every time one of those other controls is modified, which affects the apps responsiveness.  I have been looking for a couple of days for another solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?  The best case solution would allow me to access all of the data I need when the AjaxFileUpload control does a postback.

Answer (score -1):

you could have a ajax function that is reading changes from time to time external data, and update the information displayed, similar to email alerts, sorry for my English.